# A varchar conversion to a datetime type

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I wonder if with this conversion I have 100% certainty that the time for the my_date column will be properly converted, in general, that the whole date will look correct after the conversion.

The date will always be correctly converted from the format `dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss` to the format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`?

What is the best conversion for this case?

Below is an example for the problem described:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (my_date VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('25-02-2019 19:30:12')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('01-03-2019 09:30:11')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('22-02-2018 19:42:12')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('01-11-2019 19:30:17')

SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, my_date, 105) FROM @tmp
```

Comment: 105 is the Italian (`'dd-MM-yyyy'`) style code, so if that is the format of your `varcahr`, yes, it will always work. [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles)

Comment: @Larnu But 105 is without time

Comment: I think someone hasn't tested, @KillerQueen. :)

Comment: @Larnu I tested it and it works, but read the question `100% certainty`, `the best solution`

Comment: Yes, because that's what style 105 is for, dates of the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. That is what the documentation tells you. If you beleive the documentation is wrong, then Stack Overflow isn't the place, you should be raising the concern on the mssql-docs github.

Comment: @Larnu I know this :) But what happens with this time, how it is converted

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '25-02-2019 19:30:12',105);` returns `2019-02-25 19:30:12.000`. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Larnu Several test cases that work do not give me a guarantee!
And I have nothing to document, but I did not find in it information on how the time is converted since the mask for 105 is only `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: I think what your asking about here is a non-issue. `hh:mm:ss(.sssssss)` is the ISO format for times; it isn't going to pose an issue.

Comment: @killer if you have any doubts, just use `SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME, my_date + ' 00:00:00', 105)`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (my_date VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('25-02-2019 19:30:12')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('01-03-2019 09:30:11')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('22-02-2018 19:42:12')
INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES ('01-11-2019 19:30:17')

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DATETIME, my_date, 105),120) FROM @tmp
```